# Remove equal width constraint and make one to be full width

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I have this kind of layout

[image]

Each Service No and Direction has their own outer UIView to contain each views, with some of important constraints:

- Service No outer box has equal width with Direction outer box
- Service No has trailing space 3px with Direction outer box

As in Direction outer box does not have width, so I cannot set the width into 0, so that the Service No can occupy the full width (but with -3px at moment).

Anyone has advise how to achieve my goal?

Comment: Why not stackview?

Answer (score -1):

Give Service No outer box leading constraint to the container UIView and similarly give Direction outer box a trailing constraint to the Container UIView.